# How to get Mysql comments to show up in the slow-log or processlist?

Tags: mysql, comments, profiling, mysql-slow-query-log

I'm using the mysql [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/slow-query-log.html) and `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` to debug some slow queries.

MySQL allows comments to be added with the standard `/* ... */` [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comments.html). I was hoping by adding a comment in front of my query, it will be easier to spot the origin of some of our queries. For example, many times in the slow-log I just see `commit` so I know the transaction is slow but I find it hard to determine more details about the origin of the queries.

To test this trick, I'm using:

```
 SELECT /* GREP-HOOK */ SLEEP(3);
```

I was hoping the "GREP-HOOK" comment would show up in `SHOW [FULL] PROCESSLIST` and in the `log/slow-log` file. However it doesn't.

Anyone know if there's a `my.cnf` setting that will allow comments to show in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`?

---

For reference:

```
> mysqld --version
mysqld  Ver 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.13.10.1-log for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

(but I also want to try this in [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) 5.5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was testing with the mysql **command line client**. It turns out that the command line client strips the comments before sending to the server (which [could be a bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26215)).

When I tested using a PHP script, the comment was retained fine, and appeared in the slow-log as I wanted.

---

For reference, my mysql client version is:

```
> mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.34, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the mysql client you can invoke it with the `--comments, -c` option so it "preserves comments sent to the server" (see `man mysql`)

Comment: Thank you for saving me from hundreds of `man mysql` lines...